# How can you set up a server for Twilio on IBM Bluemix? Step-by-step

Tags: java, server, twilio, ibm-cloud

Looking to use Twilio API on Bluemix but need to set-up the server side for Twilio to be able to respond to SMS. We've looked into the Liberty for Java service but still not sure how it all comes together. Looking for a simple step-by-step to go through setting up Twilio, server on Bluemix.

Answer (score 2):

Handling SMS messages from the Twilio API will require you to...

1. Register for a [Twilio phone number](https://www.twilio.com/user/account/phone-numbers/incoming)
2. Configure that number with an external webhook for SMS messages
3. Write a Java HTTP Servlet to process and respond to TwilML requests

Once you've purchased a number, the number account page will have a form allowing you to specify an external URL to be used as a webhook when new SMS messages arrive. Twilio will post the TwilML message to this URL with the full details. The server can respond with TwilML content to control the response.

This URL will be the external URL on IBM Bluemix of the your web application, http://your_app_name.mybluemix.net.

Twilio has an excellent [Java client library](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-java).

There is a [Quickstart tutorial for Java](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/), will walk you through many sample scenarios for using the service, including [handling SMS messages](https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/sms/hello-monkey).

Comment: Here is an example using Spring if you are interested https://github.com/IBM-Bluemix/session-questions/blob/master/session-questions-text/src/main/java/net/bluemix/questions/text/controller/TwilioController.java